# Runtime error with sorting list when elements are not hardcoded

Tags: java, arrays, list

I'm sorting a list of string arrays according to a custom sorting. Everything works fine when I hard code entries into the list. However, when I generate entries by code, I get the error. Can you please explain me what is going wrong?

**Hard code**

```
list.add(new String[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "F"});
```

**Real code**

```
String[] varriables = new String[5];
// Sperate fix message
String[] breakDown = strLine.split("\\|");

// Build sub array for sorting
for (String s : breakDown) {
    if (s.startsWith("55=")) {
        varriables[0] = s.substring(3);
    } else if (s.startsWith("1=")) {
        varriables[1] = s.substring(2);
    } else if (s.startsWith("109=")) {
        varriables[2] = s.substring(4);
    } else if (s.startsWith("54=")) {
        varriables[3] = s.substring(3);
    }
    varriables[4] = strLine;
}
list.add(varriables);
```

**Sorting (line 113)**

```
list.sort(byIndices(2, 3));
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Comparator$$Lambda$2/41359092.compare(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Comparator.lambda$thenComparing$36697e65$1(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Comparator$$Lambda$4/821270929.compare(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(Unknown Source)
    at Foo.main(Foo.java:113)
```

*EDIT*

**byIndices**

```
static Comparator<String[]> byIndices(int first, int... rest) {
        Comparator<String[]> comparator = comparing((array) -> array[first]);
        for (int index : rest) {
            comparator = comparator.thenComparing((array) -> array[index]);
        }
        return comparator;
    }
```

**Declaring List**

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code - `byIndices`, the declaration of `list`, etc...

Comment: Presumably some element of `varriables` is null, presumably because `strLine` didn't include everything you expected it to. Have you looked at `varriables` *before* sorting?

Comment: @Eran: What makes you say that? All of the branches could be hit with suitable input.

Comment: @JonSkeet oh that could be possible

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that sometimes the values were null. Thanks for the comments. Added this to fix:

```
varriables[0] = "";
varriables[1] = "";
varriables[2] = "";
varriables[3] = "";
```

Comment: It would be simpler to change your declaration to `String[] variables = { "", "", "", "", "" };` But is it *valid* for some of those array elements never to get hit? That suggests your line doesn't contain all the pieces you expected - is that okay, or does it mean that either you've got bogus data or your data extraction is broken?